# Domino 8.5.3 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, ibm-domino

Is Domino 8.5.3 stable on Windows server 2012? I am trying to decide if I should run Domino on win 2008 or win 2012?  Does anyone have any experience in running this on Win server 2012?

Answer (score 4):

Support for Windows Server 2012 was introduced with IBM Domino 9 Social Edition (March 2013) and 8.5.3 Fix Pack 4 (April 2013).

Answer (score 2):

Since IBM's [System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27022468) for Windows only goes up to Server 2008 R2, even if you were to get Domino installed and working on 2012 - they would not support you if you needed to call in for support. I suggest going with the system requirements, as to save yourself for being SOL for support or the frustration of trying to get Domino up and running on 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Domino 8.5.3 on Windows Server 2012 with no problems.

However, I agree with Cole that it is an unsupported configuratin.

Comment: Brave lad.  Production or test?

Comment: Production (a single hosted server, only)

Comment: Thank you Per and Cole.  I'll go the safe route with server 2008.  Cheers!...Rob